# how to use macro with an argument in the `uvm_object_utils

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I create sequence class like this:

```
`define SEQ_NAME(sub_name) ``sub_name``_test_seq

class base_sequence extends uvm_sequence;
    `uvm_object_utils(base_sequence)
......
endclass

class `SEQ_NAME(abc) extends base_sequence;
    `uvm_object_utils(`SEQ_NAME(abc))
......
endclass
```

and then I want to use `set_type_override_by_name` to override base_sequence :

```
factory.set_type_override_by_name("base_sequence","abc_test_seq");  //fatal, abc_test_seq is not registered with the factory
```

I find that the  `` `uvm_object_utils(`SEQ_NAME(abc)) `` is expanded like this:

```
typedef uvm_object_registry#(abc_test_seq,"`SEQ_NAME(abc)") type_id;
......
```

I modify my override code :

```
factory.set_type_override_by_name("base_sequence","`SEQ_NAME(abc)");  //PASS
```

So, if I want to use the string "abc_test_seq" in override factory, should the `uvm_obeject_utils`  be passed the `abc_test_seq` argument? Is there any ways to use macro like my second class?

Answer (score 0):

A back-tick (`` ` ``) inside a double quotes is treated as a string character and not the prefix of a macro. You should create a new macro that add quotes around it input argument. The argument will be evaluated before the quotes added. For example:

```
`define STR(str) `"str`"
```

Then you can do:

```
typedef uvm_object_registry#(abc_test_seq,`STR(`SEQ_NAME(abc))) type_id;
...
factory.set_type_override_by_name("base_sequence",`STR(`SEQ_NAME(abc)));
```

In this case, `` `STR(`SEQ_NAME(abc) `` will resolve as to `"abc_test_seq"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I try this method, but in the simulation, it still be resolve as "`SEQ_NAME(abc)"

Comment: @herbert.x which simulator? I tried it on three different simulators on EDAplayground and they all evaluated as expected